golang crypto/elliptic Curve relationship to crypto/ecdh Curve
Is there an easy way to go from a ecdh.Curve to an  elliptic.Curve?  Specifically I'm interested in the Params exposed by the elliptic package.
The ecdh interface doesn't seem to expose any relationship, though certainly it has all that same information in the implementation of the nistCurve.

Seeing how the crypto/elliptic package says it's deprecated for any use of ecdh, and the crypto/ecdh package should be used instead, I doubt there's a builtin way to go from one to the other. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Just something like - given an ecdh.PublicKey, log the curve name or use the BitSize to verify I can copy it.  Basically the sort of info available on the elliptic.Curve.Params`.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Most of crypto/elliptic is deprecated but, according to the crypto/ecdh documentation, you can write a switch statement to do the conversion:
import (
    "crypto/ecdh"
    "crypto/elliptic"
    "errors"
)

func ECDHToElliptic(curve ecdh.Curve) (elliptic.Curve, error) {
    switch curve {
    case ecdh.P256():
        return elliptic.P256(), nil
    case ecdh.P384():
        return elliptic.P384(), nil
    case ecdh.P521():
        return elliptic.P521(), nil
    default:
        return nil, errors.New("non-NIST curve")
    }
}

